# Problems with Dual Boot om Packard Bell TE69BM

Tags: boot, uefi

I want to install Ubuntu on a Packard Bell EasyNote TE 69 BM. 
Go into the bios and will change the Boot Mode but it is not possible. 
There's only one option UEFI and Secure Boot, I can not change. 
Anyone know how to access and modify this?

Have now managed to put Secure Boot to disable. 
Has done just about everything that is in these three descriptions.

- http://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/
- http://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/

Sorry, can not post more than 2 links
But still can not boot from USB, n 
When I go into the Boot Manager so there are only

1. Windows Boot Manager
2. Network Boot

When I go into the Windows (flag + C) "change computer settings" "update / restore" "restore" "Advanced Start" "Restart" "Use a Device" "EFI USB Device" so it will come up after some time "System does't have any USB boot option. Please select other boot options"

Responds ok and the computer restarts and goes into Windows. 
What do I do wrong? Has anyone solved this problem? 
And how did you do That?

Answer (score 0):

Enable Secure Boot mode

Hit Enter on "Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing"

Browse to EFI/BOOT on your USB stick and select the corresponding file

(you might have too put a 32-bit EFI file on there if your BIOS doesn't support 64-bit
UEFI)

Reboot

Answer (score 0):

> When I go into the Windows (flag + C) "change computer settings" "update / restore" "restore" "Advanced Start" "Restart" "Use a Device" "EFI USB Device" so it will come up after some time "System does't have any USB boot option. Please select other boot options"

Sounds like there is an issue with the media you created. Could you please have a look at *[How to create UEFI-only bootable USB live media?](https://askubuntu.com/q/395879/40581)* and try again following these instructions?